# No module named ‘picamera'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I followed this website
(https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/) to set my picamera, but I have a problem with the picamera module. I did install the picamera module, and this picture is from pip freeze.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpqtr.jpg

You can see I have picamera 1.13 already, but when I try test_image.py, it says "No module named ‘picamera'".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEwPB.jpg

I have uninstalled and installed many times, but the error still exist. How do I fix this?

```
test_image.py

# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera)

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# grab an image from the camera
camera.capture(rawCapture, format="bgr")
image = rawCapture.array

# display the image on screen and wait for a keypress
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Try `pip3 install picamera`

Comment: There are 2 main versions of Python, i.e. Python 2.7 and Python 3.x. If you are just getting started with Python, IMHO you should use Python 3 which has been out and about around 10-11 years. So make sure that you run Python3 and its little friend `pip3`. Therefore use a shebang at the start that clearly says which Python you are expecting and check what's going on with `type python`, `type python3` and `type pip` and `type pip3`.

Comment: @NutCracker the error still exist

Comment: I should reset  the SD card. After I  reinstalled so many times and many things, I was confused about the state of my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 5):

for python3 you have to just try this below commands.keep in mind that you need to open terminal in home directory.

```
sudo -H apt install python3-picamera
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade picamera[array]
```

let me know if it works!

Answer (score 2):

When you run the command **pip3 install picamera**, it will show that the requirement is already satisfied followed by a **path**, provided if you have already installed picamera. Now copy that path and include it in your program as follows:

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('paste the copied path here')
    from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
    from picamera import PiCamera
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem until I noticed that I didn't capitalized c in PiCamera

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands from:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md

I'm assuming the path for the picamera module is messed up for some reason, so try purging it and reinstalling it.

Purge using:

```
sudo apt purge python3-picamera
```

First make sure everything is up to date:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install python3-picamera
```

Answer (score -1):

Pi camera may not work on windows try following commands, it will resolve issue

execute:

```
set READTHEDOCS=True
```

Now execute:

```
pip install picamera
```

Answer (score -1):

When I had a file named picamera.py, I had the same problem so I renamed it and since more problem.
I hope it's the same for you, otherwise it's above my skills.

Answer (score -3):

Install the picamera Module using the steps below

`1.On Windows, execute: set READTHEDOCS=True`

`1'.On Unix based systems, execute: export READTHEDOCS=True`

`2.Now execute: pip install picamera`